# Nginx: Access-Control-Allow-Origin not working for specific locations

Tags: nginx

I added the Access-Control-Allow-Origin under the server section. That works as expected for any 'images'. When I call the 'canonical link' (1.pdf) the Access-Control-Allow-Origin is missing in the response. Why? And how can that be solved?

I don't want do add this line to all of my canonical links.

```
server {
    server_name myserver.de;
    listen 10.11.12.13:443 ssl http2;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/ssl_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/ssl_error.log error;

    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://foo.bar';

    location / {
        root /data/images/;

        location ~ (.*)/1.pdf$ {
            #add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://foo.bar';
            add_header Link "<http://foo.bar/a-pdf>; rel=\"canonical\"";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> There could be several add_header directives. These directives are
>   inherited from the previous level if and only if there are no
>   add_header directives defined on the current level.

You can use `ngx_headers_more` module to solve this problem

If you don't want to use above module, try something like this

```
server {
    set $headerA 'https://foo.bar';
    set $headerB "";

    if (something) {
            set $headerB "something";
    }

    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $headerA;
    add_header Link $headerB;
}
```

Only use add_header in the server block and remove all add_header from location block. Note that `Link` would not be returned if `headerB` is empty

Comment: So If I don't install this ngx_headers_more extension, I 've to add the 'add_header' to every other location? I've ~ 50 canonical links...